# Android simple app with TabActivity

Tags: android, tabactivity

I am new to Android and I have been trying to reuse the tutorial on the Android developer website about developing a TabActivity App but, unfortunately, it never worked, even when I constructed it the exact same way as it is described…
Using the debugger it seemed the problem came from the main layout.

`-> setContentView(R.layout.main); //After this line the app stops.`

Here is my main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
 android:id="@android:id/tabhost"   
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">    
 <LinearLayout        
  android:orientation="vertical"        
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"        
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"        
  android:padding="5dp">        
  <TabWidget            
   android:id="@android:id/tabs"            
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"            
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" />        
  <FrameLayout            
   android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"            
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"            
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"            
   android:padding="5dp" />    
 </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

If anyone had the same problem, or if someone have some advices they are welcome :)

Tanks a lot!

Randy

Comment: What is the error message? Does it complain about not being able to find main? Or does it complain about the layout file itself?

Comment: Try to catch the exception and see what it is: try { setContentView(R.layout.main); } catch (Exception e) {Log.v("tag","exception",e);}

Answer (score 1):

The xml you posted is the same as the [TabHost example](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html) and there is nothing wrong with it.
There must be something in your code.

Please post the code otherwise we can not help you.